# Calculate ratios of multiple treatments to control within groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like the following example, with three factors that are essentially blocking variables (Z, A, and B), one factor that describes the treatment (X), and a numeric response (Y). Within each combination of Z, A and B, I would like to calculate the ratio of Y for each level of X compared to the reference level (X=="a").

```
df<-data.frame(expand.grid(Z=c("Left","Right","Centre"),A=c("Yesterday","Tomorrow"),B=c("Rep1","Rep2"),X=c("a","b","c")))
set.seed(83)
df$Y<-sample(1:10,nrow(df),replace=T)
```

This dplyr code seems to achieve that:

```
ratios <- df %>%
  group_by(Z,A,B) %>% 
  reframe(ratio = Y/Y[X=="a"])
ratios
```

However, I would really like another column in there that tells me which level of X the ratio is associated with, and I can't work out how to get this.

Or is the output faithful to the row order of the original dataframe? (even if there are NAs?)

(I'm trying to do this with a bigger dataset, and something is not working - either the row order is changing, or something is not working with group_by. Annoyingly I can't seem to recreate the error with a small example dataset...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you describe the error you are getting? The first observation you could make is that your output has exactly as many rows as your original dataframe because your `reframe()` is equivalent to `mutate()` + sorting in this case. With `mutate()`, you automatically keep the `X` row:

```r
df |> 
  group_by(Z, A, B) |>  
  mutate(ratio = Y / Y[X == "a"]) |> 
  arrange(Z, A, B)
#> # A tibble: 36 × 6
#> # Groups:   Z, A, B [12]
#>    Z     A         B     X         Y  ratio
#>    <fct> <fct>     <fct> <fct> <int>  <dbl>
#>  1 Left  Yesterday Rep1  a         1  1    
#>  2 Left  Yesterday Rep1  b        10 10    
#>  3 Left  Yesterday Rep1  c        10 10    
#>  4 Left  Yesterday Rep2  a         4  1    
#>  5 Left  Yesterday Rep2  b        10  2.5  
#>  6 Left  Yesterday Rep2  c         6  1.5  
#>  7 Left  Tomorrow  Rep1  a         9  1    
#>  8 Left  Tomorrow  Rep1  b         2  0.222
#>  9 Left  Tomorrow  Rep1  c         8  0.889
#> 10 Left  Tomorrow  Rep2  a         9  1    
#> # ℹ 26 more rows
```

Comment: This answers my question, thanks! My problem was that without the X column, I couldn't see how `reframe` was sorting the data, so I was mixing up which ratio was associated with which X (and actually this was also happening in the example, I just hadn't spotted it). `mutate` works because it keeps the X, and the suggestion of adding `arrange` for more flexibility is also helpful.